# Word Formation with A,B,C

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability that a randomly generated 7-letter word using only the letters A, B, C, contains CAB as a subword? (Note: For example, CAB is a subword of CCABAAA, but not a subword of CAABACB.)

My try:

Total Number of ways you could have 7-letter word with A,B and C = $3^{7}$ = 2187

Possible ways CAB could be arranged is

Case i) CAB_ _ _ _

Case ii) _CAB _ _ _

Case iii) _ _ CAB _ _

Case iv) _ _ _ CAB _

Case v) _ _ _ _ CAB

For all these cases you could $5*3^{4}$ ways = 405

Now you will have to subtract CABCAB_, CAB_CAB, _CABCAB = 9 ways.

So the answer is (405-9)/2187 = 396/2187.

Could someone verify my answer?

Thanks

Satish

Comment: CABCAB_is counted under CAB_ _ _ _ and CAB_CAB is counted under _ _ _ _CAB and _CABCAB is counted under _ _ _ _CAB and that is why you have to subtract 3 ways

Comment: Well, each is counted 3 times (since you can fill in that remaining slot in 3 ways), so you need to subtract $3(3)$. The bigger issue is why are you *dividing* by $2187$? For one thing, you're getting that the "number of ways" is not an integer.

Comment: I thought we are supposed to calculate the probability

Comment: You are right I have to subtract 9 then the probability would be (405-9)/2187.  Thanks

Comment: Oh my apologies, I misread! So then strike the last sentence.

Comment: Yes, it’s correct, though I’d reduce the fraction to $\frac{44}{243}$.